# Java get month sort name from date

Tags: java

I need to get month short name and date from the following date format.

Given date format is : `2015-12-01 00:00:00`  and my output date format is `Dec, 01` . but my code always return `Jan, 01`. please tell me where I am wrong in my code.

```
    String newdate = "";
    String ip = "2015-10-01 00:00:00";
    try {
        String old_format = "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss";
        String new_format = "MMM, dd";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(old_format);
        Date d = sdf.parse(ip);
        SimpleDateFormat sm = new SimpleDateFormat(new_format);
        newdate = sm.format(d);
        System.out.println(newdate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your old format should be `String old_format = "yyyy-`MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

Comment: 'm' is for minutes. You should use 'M' instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the expected result you should use the following format:

```
String old_format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
```

`MM` instead of `mm` to get the two digit month of the year

Please check the table on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

> > `M` -> Month in year
> >
> > `m` -> Minute in hour

Answer (score 1):

The old_format should be :

```
String old_format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"; //mm -> MM
```

And instead of doing

```
SimpleDateFormat sm = new SimpleDateFormat(new_format);
```

You can also use the applyPattern() method to change the pattern of the SimpleDataFormat:

```
sdf.applyPattern(new_format);
newdate = sdf.format(d);
```

So you don't have to create another SimpleDataFormat Object.

Answer (score 1):

As the other said, use:

```
String old_format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"; //mm -> MM
```

If you're using Java SE 8 or later (recommended), try using the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

```
DateTimeFormatter oldFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(old_format);
DateTimeFormatter newFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(new_format);
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(ip, oldFormatter);
String newdate = dateTime.format(newFormatter);
// and later optionally
MonthDay monthDay = MonthDay.parse(newdate, newFormatter);
```